# git hook not running in Mac Monterey

Tags: git, githooks

I have a pre-commit hook that is not running. I already tried with different shebangs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# tried:
#/bin/zsh
#/bin/sh
#/usr/bin/bash
#/usr/bin/zsh
#/usr/bin/sh
#/usr/bin/env
#/usr/bin/env zsh
#/usr/bin/env bash
#/usr/bin/env sh
```

I tried giving it permission with

```
chmod ug+x .git/hooks/*
```

The hook has no extension as requested. after I try git commit nothing happens other than the usual "files changed, etc" text

Comment: what is the name of the file?

Comment: its `pre-commit`

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us the contents of the hook and to tell us what you expected to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, It worked once I moved it to `/.githooks` folder instead of `.git/hooks`. The issue was that my `core.hooksPath` was pointing to `/.githooks`